# What is CALayer and CAGradientLayer?

Tags: animation, storyboard, calayer, swift5, xcode11

Can anyone please explain what is CALayer And CAGradientLayer in simple language and how can I achieve the following gradient programmatically.

I want to achieve this gradient colour programmatically:

[image: gradient]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do some searching for `CALayer` and `CAGradientLayer` and read up on what they are, and how to use them.

However, for a very simple example...

A `CAGradientLayer` uses an array of colors (`CGColor` type), combined with an array of locations (percentages where the colors should change), and starting and ending points.

So, to get your color gradient, you want an array of colors:

```
[.purple, .blue, .green, .yellow, .red]
```

an array of locations:

```
[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0]
```

and you want to start at the Top and end at the Bottom:

```
gradLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
gradLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
```

Here's a simple example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let gradLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let myColors: [UIColor] = [.purple, .blue, .green, .yellow, .red]
        
        // assign the colors (we're using map to convert UIColors to CGColors)
        gradLayer.colors = myColors.map({$0.cgColor})
        
        // locations can be considered Percentages
        // so, 0.2 is 20%, 0.4 is 40%, etc
        gradLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0]
        
        // start at the top
        gradLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        
        // end at the bottom
        gradLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)

        view.layer.addSublayer(gradLayer)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        // layers do not auto-size, so update the frame
        gradLayer.frame = view.bounds
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Play with the locations and colors to see the differences.

Comment: hey @DonMag thank you for your answer , Can You please also tell something about that viewDidLayoutSubviews() function , like when is it called and how many times it is called?

Comment: @YuvrajAgarkar - that is fundamental iOS development. Best thing to do is read the documentation.